# How to view pending SCSI requests?

Tags: dvd, scsi, deadlock, optical-media

If the PC sends a request to read a sector on an optical disc, which turns out to be unreadable, the drive deadlocks the program into responselessness and motionlessness, until it returns the sector or an error.

During the time the program is locked by the drive, which makes the program effectively a slave, how can I see the pending SCSI request with details such as read retry count and requested LBA?

Comment: There is an ioctl for that but I never used it to know if it will actually give you any useful info.

Comment: The ioctl is called SG_GET_REQUEST_TABLE.